# Calling Kotlin function from java results in java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/TypeCastException (String Arrays)

Tags: java, arrays, kotlin, casting

I have a Kotlin function that returns a String array that looks something like:

```
fun getStringArrayFunction(): Array<String> {
    return objectList.map { it.StringField }.toTypedArray()
}
```

I import the library and call this function from java:

```
String[] myStringArray = getStringArrayFunction();
```

As mentioned in the title, I get the TypeCastException. Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: this error indicate that this type is not found on the classpath... do you have the `kotlin-stdlib` in it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @CodeScale, I needed to import the kotlin standard library.